# How to add click function to ui-gmap-polylines directives in Angular Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, events

In my project, I use [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps) to display google map and some shapes on the map.

I am trying to add a function to a polyline in response to a click event on the lines. I am using an array of objects and the `ui-gmap-polylines` directives to display the lines on the map. The display part works well. I saw there is an `events` property in the document, but could not get it work.

Here is my html code:

```
<ui-gmap-polylines
    idKey="id"
    models="link_list"
    path="'path'"
    stroke="'stroke'"
    clickable="'true'"
    visible="true"
    events="events"
    static="true"
    doRebuildAll = "true">
</ui-gmap-polylines>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
function add_link_to_list(link){
            var link_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(link.node_list);
            var ret = {
                id: link.id,
                path: link_path,
                stroke: {
                    color: '#6060FB',
                    weight: 3
                },
                clickable: true,
                editable: false,
                draggable: true,
                geodesic: true,
                visible: true,
                static: true,
                end_intersection: link.end_intersection,
                start_intersection: link.start_intersection
            };

            ret['events'] = {
                click: function(line,eventName,model,args){
                    alert('clicked!');

                },
                rightclick: function(){
                    alert('rightclicked!');
                }
            };
            ret['options'] = {
                              title: link.id,
                          };
            $scope.link_list.push(ret);
        }
```

I am not sure if I assign the `events` parameter in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I googled this question again and find the post by myself. I finally find the problem. You have to use `events="'events'"` in the html code. Please note the single quote inside the double quote on the right hand side of the equal sign.